# Whilst using StreamWriter I am getting the error; access is denied

Tags: c#, streamwriter, access-denied

When my code runs in `case DialogResult.No:`, I am getting the error:

> access is denied

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var message = "Love?";
    var title = "Love?";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    switch (result)
    {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            MessageBox.Show("Love!");
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string text2write = "LOVE";
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(desktopPath);
            writer.Write(text2write);
            writer.Close();
            break;  
    }
}
```

The error appears to be to do with the `StreamWriter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify the file path.

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string text2write = "LOVE";
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(desktopPath+"\\abc.txt");
writer.Write(text2write);
writer.Close();
```

It will create abc text file for you.If you have aleary file created then you have to just specify the exact path and set it true.

Syntax:

```
new System.IO.StreamWriter(string path,bool append);
```

Example:

```
new System.IO.StreamWriter(desktopPath+"\\abc.text",true);
```